# async authentication using Google APIs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I have the following code:

```
async function initApi() {
  const googleKey = await readJSON(appRoot + '/secrets/google-auth.json');

  const jwt = new google.auth.JWT(
    googleKey.client_email, null, googleKey.private_key, scopes);

  return jwt.authorize();
}

const calendar = {
  events: events,

  api: google.calendar({
    version: 'v3',
    auth: this.jwt
  }),

  list: async function() {
    await this.api.calendarList.list();
  },
};

module.exports = async () => Object.assign(calendar, { jwt: await initApi() });
```

I am continuously getting "Error login required". Yet the `jwt` resolves just fine to an access token when I log the result:

```
const Calendar = require('./above-code.js');

Calendar().then(c => console.log(c.jwt));
// { access_token: ... }

Calendar().then(c => console.log(c.list());
// Error: login required
```

I cannot work out why. It is driving me absolutely insane. I want to throw my laptop out a window.

What am I doing wrong? Is this the best pattern using `async` and `await` with `module.exports`? Is there a better way to just return the object so I can call `Calendar.list()` and get the result without having to jump through the hoops I currently do to just get the API and call the methods directly? E.g.:

```
const Calendar = require('./above-code.js');
await Calendar.list();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a break before I came back to this - the best solution for myself seems to be getting less frustrated before I keep at a frustrating problem.

Firstly, I moved the `api` property to the `initApi` function, and returned that there - that seemed to solve my question:

```
async function initApi() {
  const googleKey = await readJSON(appRoot + '/secrets/google-auth.json');

  const jwt = new google.auth.JWT(
    googleKey.client_email, null, googleKey.private_key, scopes);

  jwt.authorize();

  return google.calendar({
    version: 'v3',
    auth: jwt
  });
}

const calendar = {
  events: events,

  list: async function() {
    await this.api.calendarList.list();
  },
};

module.exports = async () => Object.assign(calendar, { api: await initApi() });
```

However a second caveat was that now it kept complaining about a `client.request` not being found - turns out Google has two sets of auth tools.

After changing to `google-auth-library` (instead of using `googleapis`'s in-built `auth.JWT`) I got a response back from the server, with no `client.request` complaints:

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const { JWT } = require('google-auth-library');

...

async function initApi() {
  const googleKey = await readJSON(appRoot + '/secrets/google-auth.json');

  const jwt = new JWT(
    googleKey.client_email, null, googleKey.private_key, scopes);

  return await google.calendar({
    version: 'v3',
    auth: jwt
  });
}
```

Now it works! Hope that helps anybody who has this problem.

*EDIT*: Furthermore, see Google's example [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs#loading-credentials-from-environment-variables) for loading auth from the downloadable JSON file from the Google API dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is somewhat hard to follow because of the way the author builds the module object.

Here is a simplified version that uses promises and does not require the `google-auth-library`.

```js
const { google } = require("googleapis");

function auth() {
  const gAccount = //

  const jwt = new google.auth.JWT(gAccount.client_email, null, gAccount.private_key, gAccount.scope);
  return jwt.authorize().then(() => google.calendar({ version: "v3", auth: jwt }));
}

function listCalendars() {
  return auth().then(calendar => {
    return calendar
      .calendarList.list({ showHidden: true })
      .then(res => res.data.items);
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You add `jwt` to the object, not as a separate variable, so it should be:

```
  google.calendar({
    version: 'v3',
    auth: this.jwt //here
}),
```

`Object.assign(calendar, { jwt: 'value' });` it is equivalent to `calendar.jwt = 'value'`. And you refer as if it were done in this way:

```
let jwt  = 'value';
  google.calendar({
    version: 'v3',
    auth: jwt //here
}),
```

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand. That's the exact code I have in the question. Can you clarify a little more?

Comment: Sorry bato it didn't look like this was the problem for me. I'll answer in a sec!